# Heroku PHP - making local changes isn't working

Tags: php, heroku

I have gone through the steps  of the Heroku process but my updates don't seem to be going through. For example, I tried this:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#push-local-changes

...but I do'nt see anything about a Twig template on the page. I am able to make changes to the "Hello" word and update those, but I can't figure out why I'm not seeing the  "This is a Twig template" stuff. Help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your local changes appear to be going through fine. Maybe you are making a mistake with the code at some point, try running the following:

`git push heroku step-2:master`

This will push what your main branch should look like after step 2 (https://github.com/heroku/php-getting-started/tree/step-2) to your app. If your app works after that, you are making a mistake with the code. If you want to revert it to what is on the master just do:

`git push heroku master`